# Connecting Rails to AWS MySQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've recently created a rails app. I pushed the initial files onto github.
My problem is that I want to connect my rails app to AWS in order to use a MySQL database. I keep seeing tutorials on EC2 and Beanstalk, but I am not sure which one I should use. I have all the drivers needed for ruby through the gem installations.

I'm looking to figure out the main differences between Beanstalk and created a MySQL instance as well as what to put in my database.yml file in my rails app to connect to a database. Thank you in advance!

Comment: is  your rails app going to also run on same AWS instance ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if question seems unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an idea, after you provision/create your instance on AWS (EC2 or wherever), you will then push your app's code to that remote server somewhere. You can do it manually via scripts, or you can use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) for this. Once your app is deployed to the server, you need to connect to the server via SSH and manually edit the `config/database.yml` file to point to the staging/production MySQL database. (I'm generalizing, but I think you just need a step in the right direction.)

Comment: Thanks Daryll! You pointed me in the right direction :) This is what I was looking for

Comment: @SomeProgrammer cool, good luck! Is this your first time deploying a Rails app? [This](https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/) was the article that I used to figure out how to do the things, I'm just not sure if it's still updated but I used it a few months ago. :)